# где в django лежат функции которые обрабатывают шаблоны

Tags: django

хотелось бы увидеть как работает regroup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перейдите в папку с установленным Python.
Далее: *site-packages -> django -> template*
В файле **defaulttags.py** вы найдёте то, что ищете.